# Вынести роли пользователей

Tags: node.js, role

Делаю добавление продуктов, если у пользвователя есть роль `user` или `admin` разрешить добавить продукт. Мой вариант реализации изложен ниже и работает. Но проблема возникнет в будущем, когда станет более двух ролей, сейчас я проверяю 
 роль так `(decoded.user_role === "admin" || decoded.user_role === "user")`, а если станет 7 ролей, не делать же мне 7 условий. Как грамотной решить такую проблему, что бы не столкниться с ней в будущем.

```
//handles url http://localhost:6001/products/add
router.post("/add", (req, res) => {
  jwt.verify(req.headers.token, "secret", (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(401).json({
        error: err
      });
    } else {
      if (decoded.user_role === "admin" || decoded.user_role === "user") {
        //read product information from request
        let product = new Product(
          req.body.prd_name,
          req.body.prd_price
        );

        db.query(product.getAddProductSQL(), (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(401).json({
              error: err
            });
          } else {
            res.status(200).json({
              message: "Product added.",
              productId: data.insertId
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({
          failed: "Unauthorized Access"
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: хранить в ролях правила доступа

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, в зависимости от динамической роли вам надо определять разное поведение, которое можно расширять при появление новых типов ролей.

Возможно вам поможет https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/strategy

> Паттерн Стратегия предлагает определить семейство схожих алгоритмов,
>   которые часто изменяются или расширяются, и вынести их в собственные
>   классы, называемые стратегиями.